# Use Microsoft Office build-in resources for add-in localization

Tags: c#, localization, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

It is possible to use MS Offices build-in localization resources?

All the tutorials/guides I have found all explain how you create your own localization resources, but it seems like a lot of work for 3 strings that are very common (Change, Ok and Cancel).